# Read in txt file with fixed width columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to open the a dat.txt file from the following website:
http://jse.amstat.org/datasets/04cars.dat.txt

And I am not sure which delimiter to use to read it into python as it is separated by spaces.

I tried `pd.read_csv('http://jse.amstat.org/datasets/04cars.dat.txt', delimiter = 'sp')` along with a several other things but nothing seems to work, as well as:

```
np.genfromtxt("http://jse.amstat.org/datasets/04cars.dat.txt", delimiter= 'sp')
```

Note the zeros and ones each represent a separate column.

Comment: You will have to preprocess that to turn it into a CSV.  No automated process could possibly tell the difference between the spaces in the model names and the spaces separating the columns.

Comment: OK, maybe I lied.  If you can create the list of column numbers for each field, you can use `pandas.read_fwf`:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) instead of `read_csv`.

> [`read_fwf` reads] a table of fixed-width formatted lines into DataFrame. 
> https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html

```py
import pandas as pd

colspecs = (
    (0, 44),
    (46, 47),
    (48, 49),
    (50, 51),
    (52, 53),
    (54, 55),
    (56, 57),
    (58, 59),
    (60, 66),
    (67, 73),
    (74, 77),
    (78, 80),
    (81, 84),
    (85, 87),
    (88, 90),
    (91, 95),
    (96, 99),
    (100, 103),
    (104, 106),
)
```

```py
data_url = "http://jse.amstat.org/datasets/04cars.dat.txt"

df = pd.read_fwf(data_url, colspecs=colspecs)
```

```py
df.columns = (
    "Vehicle Name",
    "Is Sports Car",
    "Is SUV",
    "Is Wagon",
    "Is Minivan",
    "Is Pickup",
    "Is All-Wheel Drive",
    "Is Rear-Wheel Drive",
    "Suggested Retail Price",
    "Dealer Cost",
    "Engine Size (litres)",
    "Number of Cylinders",
    "Horsepower",
    "City Miles Per Gallon",
    "Highway Miles Per Gallon",
    "Weight (pounds)",
    "Wheel Base (inches)",
    "Lenght (inches)",
    "Width (inches)",
)
```

And the output for `print(df)` would be:

```py
                        Vehicle Name  ...  Width (inches)
0        Chevrolet Aveo LS 4dr hatch  ...              66
1             Chevrolet Cavalier 2dr  ...              69
2             Chevrolet Cavalier 4dr  ...              68
3          Chevrolet Cavalier LS 2dr  ...              69
4                  Dodge Neon SE 4dr  ...              67
..                               ...  ...             ...
422         Nissan Titan King Cab XE  ...               *
423                      Subaru Baja  ...               *
424                    Toyota Tacoma  ...               *
425     Toyota Tundra Regular Cab V6  ...               *
426  Toyota Tundra Access Cab V6 SR5  ...               *

[427 rows x 19 columns]
```

Column names and specifications retrieved from here:

- http://jse.amstat.org/datasets/04cars.txt

---

**Note:** Don't forget to specify where each column starts and ends. Without using `colspecs`, `pandas` is making an assumption based on the first row which leads to data errors. Below an extract of a unified diff between generated `csv` files (with specs and without):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, this is a great help