# How to make Dataframe-like output to dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fetching list format depending on URL link and I want to extract terminal output to pandas Dataframe structure before doing so I must convert it to dictionary. How can I achieve that?

Here's the code:

```py
import subprocess
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjYW63CVbsE'
command = subprocess.getoutput('yt-dlp --list-formats "{url}"'.format(url=url))
print(command
```

Here's the output
[image]

I tried to split it into lines but not my expected result

```
import subprocess
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjYW63CVbsE'

command = subprocess.getoutput('yt-dlp --list-formats "{url}"'.format(url=url))
output_lines = command.split('\n')
headers = output_lines[6].split()
format_list = []
for line in output_lines[::]:
    values = line.split()
    format_info = {}
    for i in range(len(headers)):
        format_info[headers[i]] = values[i]
    format_list.append(format_info)

df = pd.DataFrame(format_list)

print(df)
```

Comment: instead of adding your output as an [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), print the first 5 lines of it and edit it into your question as text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read in txt file with fixed width columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69578559/read-in-txt-file-with-fixed-width-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against parsing the raw string and suggest using [yt_dlp.YoutubeDL](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#embedding-yt-dlp) (or use `--dump-json` or `--print "%()j"` like [the answer @AndrejKesely provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77361571/9107694)) as said in the yt-dlp doc:

> Your program should avoid parsing the normal stdout since they may change in future versions. Instead they should use options such as -J, --print, --progress-template, --exec etc to create console output that you can reliably reproduce and parse. From a Python program, you can embed yt-dlp in a more powerful fashion:

```py
import pandas as pd
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjYW63CVbsE'
ydl_opts = {'listformats':True}
with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    df = pd.DataFrame(ydl.sanitize_info(info_dict).get("formats"))
    print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   format_id format_note    ext     protocol     acodec         vcodec  ... audio_channels  language_preference  dynamic_range  container             downloader_options  filesize_approx
0        sb3  storyboard  mhtml        mhtml       none           none  ...            NaN                  NaN            NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
1        sb2  storyboard  mhtml        mhtml       none           none  ...            NaN                  NaN            NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
2        sb1  storyboard  mhtml        mhtml       none           none  ...            NaN                  NaN            NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
3        sb0  storyboard  mhtml        mhtml       none           none  ...            NaN                  NaN            NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
4        233     Default    mp4  m3u8_native        NaN           none  ...            NaN                  NaN            NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
5        234     Default    mp4  m3u8_native        NaN           none  ...            NaN                  NaN            NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
6        293     Default    mp4  m3u8_native        NaN           none  ...            NaN                  NaN            NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
7        294     Default    mp4  m3u8_native        NaN           none  ...            NaN                  NaN            NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
8        599    ultralow    m4a        https  mp4a.40.5           none  ...            2.0                 -1.0           None   m4a_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
9        600    ultralow   webm        https       opus           none  ...            2.0                 -1.0           None  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
10       139         low    m4a        https  mp4a.40.5           none  ...            2.0                 -1.0           None   m4a_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
11       249         low   webm        https       opus           none  ...            2.0                 -1.0           None  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
12       250         low   webm        https       opus           none  ...            2.0                 -1.0           None  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
13       140      medium    m4a        https  mp4a.40.2           none  ...            2.0                 -1.0           None   m4a_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
14       251      medium   webm        https       opus           none  ...            2.0                 -1.0           None  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
15        17        144p    3gp        https  mp4a.40.2      mp4v.20.3  ...            1.0                 -1.0            SDR        NaN  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
16       602         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.10.08  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
17       597        144p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4d400b  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
18       598        144p   webm        https       none            vp9  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
19       269         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D400C  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
20       281         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D400C  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
21       603         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.11.08  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
22       394        144p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.00M.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
23       160        144p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4D400C  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
24       278        144p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.11.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
25       229         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D4015  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
26       282         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D4015  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
27       604         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.20.08  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
28       395        240p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.00M.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
29       133        240p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4D4015  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
30       242        240p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.20.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
31       230         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401E  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
32       283         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401E  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
33       605         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.21.08  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
34       396        360p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.01M.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
35       134        360p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4D401E  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
36        18        360p    mp4        https  mp4a.40.2    avc1.42001E  ...            2.0                 -1.0            SDR        NaN  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}        9195945.0
37       243        360p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.21.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
38       231         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401F  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
39       284         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401F  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
40       606         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.30.08  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
41       397        480p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.04M.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
42       135        480p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4D401F  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
43       244        480p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.30.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
44       287         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401F  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
45       232         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401F  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
46       609         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.31.08  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
47        22        720p    mp4        https  mp4a.40.2    avc1.64001F  ...            2.0                 -1.0            SDR        NaN  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}       16860413.0
48       398        720p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.05M.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
49       136        720p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4D401F  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
50       247        720p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.31.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
51       290         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.640028  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
52       270         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.640028  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
53       614         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.40.08  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
54       399       1080p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.08M.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
55       137       1080p    mp4        https       none    avc1.640028  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
56       248       1080p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.40.08  ...            NaN                 -1.0            SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
57       616     Premium    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.40.08  ...            NaN                  NaN            SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN

[58 rows x 37 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with, let me know if this is what you meant:

```
    import subprocess
    import pandas as pd
    
    # Run the yt-dlp command and capture the output
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjYW63CVbsE'
    command = subprocess.getoutput(f'yt-dlp --list-formats "{url}"')
    
    # Process the output and extract relevant information
    lines = command.split('\n')
    data = []
    
    # Find the index where format information starts
    start_index = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "Format code" in line:
            start_index = i
            break
    
    # Process the lines containing format information using a dictionary
    for line in lines[start_index:]:
        parts = line.split()
        if len(parts) >= 5:
            format_id, extension, resolution, note = parts[0], parts[1], parts[3], " ".join(parts[4:])
            data.append({
                "Format ID": format_id,
                "Extension": extension,
                "Resolution": resolution,
                "Note": note
            })
    
    # Create a Pandas DataFrame from the processed data
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    # Display the DataFrame
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Format ID     Extension Resolution                                          Note
0   [youtube]  kjYW63CVbsE:        ios                                    player API JSON
1   [youtube]  kjYW63CVbsE:    android                                    player API JSON
2   [youtube]  kjYW63CVbsE:       m3u8                                        information
3      [info]     Available        for                                       kjYW63CVbsE:
4          ID           EXT        FPS  CH | FILESIZE TBR PROTO | VCODEC VBR ACODEC AB...
```

You were on the right track. If we loop through the output, we can split each line into 'parts' and separate them with spaces. Then using those parts, we can run them through a dictionary corresponding with the column names and values (keys) we want to associate with them.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to dump the data in Json format and then parse it with `json` module. It will be easier and more correct:

#### The command

```
yt-dlp --dump-json https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjYW63CVbsE
```

Then (`data.json` is the output from the above command, you can get the output from `subprocess` etc. too):

```py
import json
import pandas as pd


with open("data.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

df = pd.DataFrame(data["formats"])

# remove columns we don't want:
df.pop("url")
df.pop("manifest_url")
df.pop("fragments")
df.pop("http_headers")

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   format_id format_note    ext     protocol     acodec         vcodec   width  height        fps  rows  columns  resolution  aspect_ratio audio_ext video_ext       vbr      abr       tbr                       format  format_index language  preference  quality has_drm  source_preference      asr    filesize  audio_channels  language_preference dynamic_range  container             downloader_options  filesize_approx
0        sb3  storyboard  mhtml        mhtml       none           none    48.0    27.0   0.462963  10.0     10.0       48x27          1.78      none      none     0.000    0.000       NaN     sb3 - 48x27 (storyboard)           NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN                NaN      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
1        sb2  storyboard  mhtml        mhtml       none           none    80.0    45.0   0.504630  10.0     10.0       80x45          1.78      none      none     0.000    0.000       NaN     sb2 - 80x45 (storyboard)           NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN                NaN      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
2        sb1  storyboard  mhtml        mhtml       none           none   160.0    90.0   0.504630   5.0      5.0      160x90          1.78      none      none     0.000    0.000       NaN    sb1 - 160x90 (storyboard)           NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN                NaN      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
3        sb0  storyboard  mhtml        mhtml       none           none   320.0   180.0   0.504630   3.0      3.0     320x180          1.78      none      none     0.000    0.000       NaN   sb0 - 320x180 (storyboard)           NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN                NaN      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
4        233     Default    mp4  m3u8_native        NaN           none     NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN  audio only           NaN       mp4      none     0.000      NaN       NaN   233 - audio only (Default)           NaN       ko         NaN     -1.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
5        234     Default    mp4  m3u8_native        NaN           none     NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN  audio only           NaN       mp4      none     0.000      NaN       NaN   234 - audio only (Default)           NaN       ko         NaN     -1.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
6        293     Default    mp4  m3u8_native        NaN           none     NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN  audio only           NaN       mp4      none     0.000      NaN       NaN   293 - audio only (Default)           NaN       ko         NaN     -1.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
7        294     Default    mp4  m3u8_native        NaN           none     NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN  audio only           NaN       mp4      none     0.000      NaN       NaN   294 - audio only (Default)           NaN       ko         NaN     -1.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           NaN        NaN                            NaN              NaN
8        599    ultralow    m4a        https  mp4a.40.5           none     NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN  audio only           NaN       m4a      none     0.000   30.827    30.827  599 - audio only (ultralow)           NaN       ko         NaN      1.0   False               -1.0  22050.0    830871.0             2.0                 -1.0          None   m4a_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
9        600    ultralow   webm        https       opus           none     NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN  audio only           NaN      webm      none     0.000   32.806    32.806  600 - audio only (ultralow)           NaN       ko         NaN      1.0   False               -1.0  48000.0    883906.0             2.0                 -1.0          None  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
10       139         low    m4a        https  mp4a.40.5           none     NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN  audio only           NaN       m4a      none     0.000   48.828    48.828       139 - audio only (low)           NaN       ko         NaN      2.0   False               -1.0  22050.0   1316058.0             2.0                 -1.0          None   m4a_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
11       249         low   webm        https       opus           none     NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN  audio only           NaN      webm      none     0.000   48.621    48.621       249 - audio only (low)           NaN       ko         NaN      2.0   False               -1.0  48000.0   1310003.0             2.0                 -1.0          None  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
12       250         low   webm        https       opus           none     NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN  audio only           NaN      webm      none     0.000   64.403    64.403       250 - audio only (low)           NaN       ko         NaN      2.0   False               -1.0  48000.0   1735198.0             2.0                 -1.0          None  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
13       140      medium    m4a        https  mp4a.40.2           none     NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN  audio only           NaN       m4a      none     0.000  129.497   129.497    140 - audio only (medium)           NaN       ko         NaN      3.0   False               -1.0  44100.0   3489536.0             2.0                 -1.0          None   m4a_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
14       251      medium   webm        https       opus           none     NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN  audio only           NaN      webm      none     0.000  128.014   128.014    251 - audio only (medium)           NaN       ko         NaN      3.0   False               -1.0  48000.0   3449051.0             2.0                 -1.0          None  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
15        17        144p    3gp        https  mp4a.40.2      mp4v.20.3   176.0   144.0   8.000000   NaN      NaN     176x144          1.22      none       3gp       NaN      NaN    80.575          17 - 176x144 (144p)           NaN       ko        -2.0      0.0   False               -1.0  22050.0   2171703.0             1.0                 -1.0           SDR        NaN  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
16       602         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.10.08   256.0   144.0  15.000000   NaN      NaN     256x144          1.78      none       mp4    89.650    0.000    89.650                602 - 256x144           NaN      NaN         NaN      0.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
17       597        144p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4d400b   256.0   144.0  15.000000   NaN      NaN     256x144          1.78      none       mp4    32.126    0.000    32.126         597 - 256x144 (144p)           NaN     None         NaN      0.0   False               -1.0      NaN    865343.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
18       598        144p   webm        https       none            vp9   256.0   144.0  15.000000   NaN      NaN     256x144          1.78      none      webm    24.875    0.000    24.875         598 - 256x144 (144p)           NaN     None         NaN      0.0   False               -1.0      NaN    670135.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
19       269         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D400C   256.0   144.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     256x144          1.78      none       mp4   170.759    0.000   170.759                269 - 256x144           NaN      NaN         NaN      0.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
20       281         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D400C   256.0   144.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     256x144          1.78      none       mp4   194.390    0.000   194.390                281 - 256x144           NaN      NaN         NaN      0.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
21       603         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.11.08   256.0   144.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     256x144          1.78      none       mp4   156.304    0.000   156.304                603 - 256x144           NaN      NaN         NaN      0.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
22       394        144p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.00M.08   256.0   144.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     256x144          1.78      none       mp4    66.777    0.000    66.777         394 - 256x144 (144p)           NaN     None         NaN      0.0   False               -1.0      NaN   1798955.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
23       160        144p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4D400C   256.0   144.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     256x144          1.78      none       mp4    65.131    0.000    65.131         160 - 256x144 (144p)           NaN     None         NaN      0.0   False               -1.0      NaN   1754611.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
24       278        144p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.11.08   256.0   144.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     256x144          1.78      none      webm    83.856    0.000    83.856         278 - 256x144 (144p)           NaN     None         NaN      0.0   False               -1.0      NaN   2259052.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
25       229         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D4015   426.0   240.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     426x240          1.77      none       mp4   360.502    0.000   360.502                229 - 426x240           NaN      NaN         NaN      5.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
26       282         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D4015   426.0   240.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     426x240          1.77      none       mp4   377.885    0.000   377.885                282 - 426x240           NaN      NaN         NaN      5.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
27       604         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.20.08   426.0   240.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     426x240          1.77      none       mp4   287.988    0.000   287.988                604 - 426x240           NaN      NaN         NaN      5.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
28       395        240p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.00M.08   426.0   240.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     426x240          1.77      none       mp4   113.528    0.000   113.528         395 - 426x240 (240p)           NaN     None         NaN      5.0   False               -1.0      NaN   3058377.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
29       133        240p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4D4015   426.0   240.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     426x240          1.77      none       mp4   129.303    0.000   129.303         133 - 426x240 (240p)           NaN     None         NaN      5.0   False               -1.0      NaN   3483363.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
30       242        240p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.20.08   426.0   240.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     426x240          1.77      none      webm   125.564    0.000   125.564         242 - 426x240 (240p)           NaN     None         NaN      5.0   False               -1.0      NaN   3382635.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
31       230         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401E   640.0   360.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     640x360          1.78      none       mp4   678.281    0.000   678.281                230 - 640x360           NaN      NaN         NaN      6.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
32       283         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401E   640.0   360.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     640x360          1.78      none       mp4   689.198    0.000   689.198                283 - 640x360           NaN      NaN         NaN      6.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
33       605         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.21.08   640.0   360.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     640x360          1.78      none       mp4   561.638    0.000   561.638                605 - 640x360           NaN      NaN         NaN      6.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
34       396        360p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.01M.08   640.0   360.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     640x360          1.78      none       mp4   211.117    0.000   211.117         396 - 640x360 (360p)           NaN     None         NaN      6.0   False               -1.0      NaN   5687362.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
35       134        360p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4D401E   640.0   360.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     640x360          1.78      none       mp4   203.596    0.000   203.596         134 - 640x360 (360p)           NaN     None         NaN      6.0   False               -1.0      NaN   5484765.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
36        18        360p    mp4        https  mp4a.40.2    avc1.42001E   640.0   360.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     640x360          1.78      none       mp4       NaN      NaN   332.608          18 - 640x360 (360p)           NaN       ko         NaN      6.0   False               -1.0  44100.0         NaN             2.0                 -1.0           SDR        NaN  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}        9195945.0
37       243        360p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.21.08   640.0   360.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     640x360          1.78      none      webm   211.864    0.000   211.864         243 - 640x360 (360p)           NaN     None         NaN      6.0   False               -1.0      NaN   5707499.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
38       231         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401F   854.0   480.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     854x480          1.78      none       mp4   960.208    0.000   960.208                231 - 854x480           NaN      NaN         NaN      7.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
39       284         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401F   854.0   480.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     854x480          1.78      none       mp4   961.602    0.000   961.602                284 - 854x480           NaN      NaN         NaN      7.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
40       606         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.30.08   854.0   480.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     854x480          1.78      none       mp4   894.157    0.000   894.157                606 - 854x480           NaN      NaN         NaN      7.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
41       397        480p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.04M.08   854.0   480.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     854x480          1.78      none       mp4   356.001    0.000   356.001         397 - 854x480 (480p)           NaN     None         NaN      7.0   False               -1.0      NaN   9590470.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
42       135        480p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4D401F   854.0   480.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     854x480          1.78      none       mp4   297.776    0.000   297.776         135 - 854x480 (480p)           NaN     None         NaN      7.0   False               -1.0      NaN   8021917.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
43       244        480p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.30.08   854.0   480.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN     854x480          1.78      none      webm   306.348    0.000   306.348         244 - 854x480 (480p)           NaN     None         NaN      7.0   False               -1.0      NaN   8252834.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
44       287         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401F  1280.0   720.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN    1280x720          1.78      none       mp4  1184.146    0.000  1184.146               287 - 1280x720           NaN      NaN         NaN      8.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
45       232         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.4D401F  1280.0   720.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN    1280x720          1.78      none       mp4  1186.825    0.000  1186.825               232 - 1280x720           NaN      NaN         NaN      8.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
46       609         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.31.08  1280.0   720.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN    1280x720          1.78      none       mp4  1511.972    0.000  1511.972               609 - 1280x720           NaN      NaN         NaN      8.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
47        22        720p    mp4        https  mp4a.40.2    avc1.64001F  1280.0   720.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN    1280x720          1.78      none       mp4       NaN      NaN   609.824         22 - 1280x720 (720p)           NaN       ko         NaN      8.0   False               -5.0  44100.0         NaN             2.0                 -1.0           SDR        NaN  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}       16860413.0
48       398        720p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.05M.08  1280.0   720.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN    1280x720          1.78      none       mp4   669.901    0.000   669.901        398 - 1280x720 (720p)           NaN     None         NaN      8.0   False               -1.0      NaN  18046727.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
49       136        720p    mp4        https       none    avc1.4D401F  1280.0   720.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN    1280x720          1.78      none       mp4   480.837    0.000   480.837        136 - 1280x720 (720p)           NaN     None         NaN      8.0   False               -1.0      NaN  12953449.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
50       247        720p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.31.08  1280.0   720.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN    1280x720          1.78      none      webm   498.662    0.000   498.662        247 - 1280x720 (720p)           NaN     None         NaN      8.0   False               -1.0      NaN  13433657.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
51       290         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.640028  1920.0  1080.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN   1920x1080          1.78      none       mp4  3609.307    0.000  3609.307              290 - 1920x1080           NaN      NaN         NaN      9.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
52       270         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none    avc1.640028  1920.0  1080.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN   1920x1080          1.78      none       mp4  3681.127    0.000  3681.127              270 - 1920x1080           NaN      NaN         NaN      9.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
53       614         NaN    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.40.08  1920.0  1080.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN   1920x1080          1.78      none       mp4  2787.526    0.000  2787.526              614 - 1920x1080           NaN      NaN         NaN      9.0   maybe               -6.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
54       399       1080p    mp4        https       none  av01.0.08M.08  1920.0  1080.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN   1920x1080          1.78      none       mp4  1133.069    0.000  1133.069      399 - 1920x1080 (1080p)           NaN     None         NaN      9.0   False               -1.0      NaN  30524177.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
55       137       1080p    mp4        https       none    avc1.640028  1920.0  1080.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN   1920x1080          1.78      none       mp4  1685.723    0.000  1685.723      137 - 1920x1080 (1080p)           NaN     None         NaN      9.0   False               -1.0      NaN  45412335.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR   mp4_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
56       248       1080p   webm        https       none  vp09.00.40.08  1920.0  1080.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN   1920x1080          1.78      none      webm  1340.340    0.000  1340.340      248 - 1920x1080 (1080p)           NaN     None         NaN      9.0   False               -1.0      NaN  36107944.0             NaN                 -1.0           SDR  webm_dash  {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}              NaN
57       616     Premium    mp4  m3u8_native       none  vp09.00.40.08  1920.0  1080.0  30.000000   NaN      NaN   1920x1080          1.78      none       mp4  5519.716    0.000  5519.716    616 - 1920x1080 (Premium)           NaN      NaN         NaN      9.0   maybe               94.0      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN           SDR        NaN                            NaN              NaN
```